# How can we install a progressive web app?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

According to my knowledge a progressive web app is just a website which runs on a mobile device on a full screen and gives native look and feel.

But is it possible to develop such a PWA which can be installed on the device?

Answer (score 1):

The essential parts of a PWA are service workers and a manifest.json which allow it to work offline, cache data, send notifications and behave more like an app in general. Most frameworks have packages that you can use to get a basic setup done for you but there are [plenty of articles out there to get you up and running](https://medium.com/dev-channel/learn-how-to-build-a-pwa-in-under-5-minutes-c860ad406ed)